How to thank others for referencing my paper? Will it seem unprofessional? Is it common practice?
There are groups who have referenced published papers of which I am a co-author. The groups who referenced are not collaborators. How can I acknowledge their intellectual input?

I don't think this is a duplicate.  That one was about whether it is ethical; this is about whether it is common or accepted.

What do you mean by "their intellectual input" in this case? A citation isn't really an intellectual input, but you can of course compliment them on their paper.

@PeterFlom I see the argument that it's not a duplicate, but I'm not totally certain what's being asked either. "Acknowledge" has the unfortunate jargon-type property of having a kind of formal definition in our line of work, but I'm not sure if the asker means it that way.

Do not thank others for referencing your work. Citations/references should be based on scientific and technical merit. Either a work is relevant and should be cited or not; notably, a work should not be cited as a favour, thank-you, or general niceties.
While just thanking others for referencing your work isn’t misconduct yet, I recommend stay clear of it to avoid giving the wrong impression.
That said, if you find their work interesting and closely related to yours you might want to reach out and suggest a collaboration in the future.
